# copy multiple files to null directory

Tags: shell, makefile

I want to check if source file exist, so I assign TO_DIR=/dev/null in my gnu makefile.

```
APPS=a b c d
install:
  cp $(APPS) $(TO_DIR)
```

- for normal case, I'll run 'TO_DIR=~/bin make install'
- for test case(just make sure file exist for copy), I'll run 'TO_DIR=/dev/null make install'

But it will failed, because /dev/null is not a pseudo directory.
Is there better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do another make target, like this:

```
check:
  file $(APPS) > /dev/null
```

`file` utility will check the existence of all the files and fail when any of these does not exist. Its output is excessive for this task, so we pipe it to `/dev/null`

You will run check like this:

```
make check
```

Comment: tks, but I don't want add extra make name. I have many sub-directory and they contains their makefile, I want to call all sub-directory's makefile.

Comment: you could probably use `/tmp` as dump directory. To get rid of your files completely and momentarily, you could fuse-mount something like  nullfs (https://github.com/xrgtn/nullfs)

Comment: Thanks, nullfs is the solution which I want.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a modification of spacediver's answer that just branches based on the value of `TO_DIR`

```
install:
    [ -z "$(TO_DIR)" ] && make install_for_real || make check

install_for_real:
    cp $(APPS) $(TO_DIR)

check:
    file $(APPS) > /dev/null
```

This should do the check for either of

```
make install
make install TO_DIR=
```

but the real installation for

```
make install TO_DIR=/path/to/installation/dir
```

Comment: thanks, you provide another smart method. That prevent installation of nullfs.

Comment: Use this to show the missing file `file $(APPS) > /dev/null || file $(APPS)`, I try to use `grep 'No such'`, but it cause another issue.